# Bind columns from downloaded data with HTTR in a single command

Tags: r

Let's say I've downloaded a list from a random URL with the `hhtr` function and gives a `response` with three columns (salary, health...).

I have these four lines of code which I want to execute in the tidyverse environment.

```
dataframe_1 <- as.data.frame(response$salary)
dataframe_2 <- as.data.frame(response$health)
dataframe_3 <- as.data.frame(response$travel)
```

```
binded_df <- bind_cols(dataframe_1, dataframe_2, dataframe_3)
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
binded_df %>%
"get the three columns in a single dataframe without creating three separate
 df and then combine them"
```

**Extra question:**

And in a scenario that this code is in a function with unknown variables and only on variable per column. How would that look like?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be helpful if you provided some more information, but it looks like you might be looking for `purrr::map_df`

Here's an example:

```
library(purrr)

 response <- list(
    travel = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1),
    salary = c(30000, 40000, 25000, 70000, 90000),
    health = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
)

purrr::map_df(response, ~.x)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  travel salary health
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> 
1      1  30000 A     
2      2  40000 B     
3      1  25000 C     
4      2  70000 D     
5      1  90000 E
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Going to test it and see if it's work.

Comment: It works. :) However, if I want to use this code in a function where the values for travel, salary and health are unknown and only are one variable. What should I put instead of c()...? @Matt

Comment: Added it to the ordinary question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - if you can, try running `dput(response_list)` and copy/paste that into your question. Then I'll be able to look at your data